# Help with Shadow(s) in Blender (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

Hello Blender community,

I ran into a problem.... What I want is to exclude the shadow that is cast by object 1on object 3. But the shadow from object 1 on object 2 must remain. How do I Fix this problem?

Hope someone can help[image]

Comment: And I guess object 3 should receive the shadow from object 2? Or should it receive no shadow at all? The latter would be easy to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

When the floor plane should receive no shadows at all, you could use this quick fix:

[image]
Remove all shaders from your ground material, and plug an RGB node directly into the Surface Pin of the Material Output. This way, only the color of the plane will be displayed, but there will be absolutely no shading (shadows, reflections, etc.) without BSDFs.

If you also want *the Sphere to cast a shadow on the ground*, things get rather complicated, as Gordon Brinkmann already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use view layers and the compositor. It's a bit messy but very powerful.

EDIT:

- In the example below I created three collections (RMB -> New over
  Collection in the outliner editor) then moved each object so it was
  in its own collection.
- I then created a new view layer, called ViewLayer_001 (click on
  the    overlapping square logo right at the top of the outliner
  editor)
- With the original ViewLayer selected, I disabled the collection with    the vertical plane casting the shadow. For this
  view layer there is    just the icosphere casting a shadow onto the
  horizontal plane.
- With ViewLayer_001 selected I set the collection with the horizontal    plane to holdout. (It's easier to see what's going on
  if you select    the filter at the top of the outliner and add the
  holdout column, but    you can set these with the RMB menu) This
  layer then renders the    icosphere and vertical plane but the
  horizontal plane is transparent.    (alph = 0)
- I then opened a compositor editor, toggled 'use nodes' at the top,          then duplicated the render layers node and changed the duplicate to ViewLayer_001. I then added a color -> alpha over node to composite    the two.

[image]

You might be able to [follow the video](https://youtu.be/5DxkbCszd4s) for my chapter 13 in get-into-blender.com - the video is rather quick without the book, and doesn't answer your question exactly, but the view layer stuff starts after the first minute or so!

Here's a simple blend file with three objects that does what I think you want. [image]

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to solve the problem. Don't make understanding your answer dependent on downloading a file or watching a video on an external site. On this site it is favoured to at least give a basic explanation rather than just saying to watch video and also you can upload files on this site https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to embed them in your answer. Links to external sites will render the answer here useless if those links expire one day or the content gets deleted.

Comment: Oh, and by the way - if the scene contains an object maybe half hidden by the floor like it seems to be the case with the icosphere in the screenshot, simply disabling the floor collection like in your example file will not give the desired result - you have to set it to _Holdout_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes to both comments. I will add some more description to the answer and fix the holdout in the example!

Comment: @all, Thanks for the input.! I will look at it.